# Why reborrowing &mut[u8] makes its size unknown at compile time?

Tags: rust

I'm creating a mutable `[u8]` buffer as this:

```
let buffer: &mut [u8] = &mut [0u8; 34];
```

and using here:

```
repr.emit(&mut *buffer, &caps.checksum);
```

and reborrowing here:

```
assert_eq!(processor!(iface).process_ip_payload(&mut ip, &mut socket_set, Instant::from_millis(0), &mut *buffer), Ok(Some(expected_repr)));
```

I get:

> the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
>
> doesn't have a size known at compile-time

for the `...,&mut *buffer)` reborrow (the last one, on assert).

The original buffer has its size known at compile time. Why reborrowing makes the size unknown?

Here are the signatures if needed:

```
    pub fn emit<T: AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>>(
        &self,
        buffer: T,
        _checksum_caps: &ChecksumCapabilities,
    )
    fn process_ip_payload<'frame, T: AsRef<[u8]>>(
        &mut self,
        ip: &mut ip::Processor,
        sockets: &mut SocketSet,
        timestamp: Instant,
        frame: &'frame T,
    ) -> Result<Option<ip::Packet<'frame>>>
```

Comment: The reason is `process_ip_payload` expects `&'frame T`. You pass `&mut [u8]`. Unification makes T to `[u8]` which is unsized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't dereference `buffer` when you pass it in as an argument:

```
assert_eq!(processor!(iface).process_ip_payload(
    &mut ip, &mut socket_set, Instant::from_millis(0), &mut buffer),
    Ok(Some(expected_repr)));
```

(`&mut buffer` instead of `&mut *buffer`).

Comment: wouldn't this make me pass a `&& [u8]`?

Comment: anyway I got `cannot borrow `buffer` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable` for `&but buffer`

Comment: @Guerlando: I think you are are almost right, is should be `&mut &mut [u8]`. And this compile error should disappear, if you declare the variable buffer as mutable `let mut buffer: &mut [u8] = &mut [0u8; 34];`. `&&[u8]` would be fine because `&'frame T` with `T:AsRef<[u8]` is satisfied.

Comment: `& buffer` instead of `&mut buffer` should also work.